# What does $\mathbb{C}^2$ represent?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm getting interested in quantum computing but I lack the mathematical background so I try to catch up.

I've seen that a qubit is represented by a two-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}^2$, but I don't know what $\mathbb{C}^2$ is. The complex number type squared? What does it mean?

Also when are you supposed to be confronted to this notion in school, high school or above ?

When I try to google this google simplify my search by $\mathbb{C}^2$ and all I get are results about speed of light because of the $E=mc^2$ equation.

Thank you

Comment: It is just the cartesian product $\Bbb C$x$\Bbb C$ i.e. all the couples $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers (reals included!).

Comment: It is the set of pairs of complex numbers: $\mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C} = \{(a,b): a\in \mathbb{C}, b\in \mathbb{C}\}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product.

Comment: It's the set of pairs of complex numbers, so it includes stuff like $(1+2i,3+4i)$. If you know about vector spaces: this is a vector space over the complex numbers. (Vector spaces are typically introduced in a linear algebra course, I think.)

Comment: See [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cartesian_Product) for a formal definition of Cartesian product. $\Bbb C^2$ is a shorthand for $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$.

Comment: You have to search for "linear algebra", "vector spaces". (First undergraduate class). However $\mathbb C^2$, means simply the cartesian product  $\mathbb C^2=\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$, that is the set of all the pairs $(z,w)$ of all the possible complex numbers $z,w\in\mathbb C$. Of course there is more than this, because usually $\mathbb C^2$ is understood as a vector space, that is a set in which you can perform some operations, in particular the sum of two couples: $(z,w)+(z',w')=(z+z',w+w')$. You can start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space. (See par.: "Second example")

Comment: In my opinion you should first understand the most basic mathematical notions and only after achieving that think about qubits, not in the reverse order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Bbb{C}^2$ is the set of all ordered pairs of complex numbers, i.e. $(z,w)$ where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers. I don't think this notation is typically used in high school classes.

More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A \times B$ is called the Certesian product of $A$ and $B$, defined as the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. For example, if $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{4,5,6\}$, then $A\times B$ has $6$ elements: $(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),$ and $(2,6)$.

$\Bbb{C}^2$ is just short for $\Bbb{C}\times\Bbb{C}$.

(in case you don't know: a set is a collection of objects, usually numbers; these objects in the set are called elements of that set; if $A$ is a set, then $a\in A$ means "$a$ is an element of $A$").